# METEOR JS: Actions with multiple users

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have 2 chat rooms, in every room I have 5 users and `input` field , where every user can enter some number and `submit` it to validate on server, if number equal (for example) to `5` than users in this room win, and users in other room lose, so I have 5 users that win and 5 that lose.

So, what I want: when one of team win, than redirect users that wins to some `WIN` page, and at the same time redirect users that lose to `LOSE` page. And **!THIS IMPORTANT!** if some users for example was offline but his team won or lose , than when the next time user log in show `LOSE` or `WIN` page which depends on whether his team won or not.

So I see 3 problems for which I do not find a solution:

1. Redirect group of users (I use `Iron Router`)
2. Track when one of team win (track for all users that play game) (Blaze `if` unsuitable)
3. If some team wins and user was `offline` , hen the next time user log in show `LOSE` or `WIN` page

I know that a lot of questions and they are very extensive, but could not find the solution, help somebody !

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to track this at the group level and then just have a template helper that tracks the group's win/loss status. You wouldn't even need a session variable and all participants would get the correct notification instantly or deferred. Ex:

HTML:

```
<template name="wrapper">
  {{#if state.inProgress}}
    {{> gameTemplate}}
  {{else}}
    {{#if state.won}}
      {{> winnnerTemplate}}
    {{else}}
      {{> loserTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

JS:

```
Template.wrapper.helpers({
  state: function(){
    var myGroupId = Meteor.user().myGroupId;
    var outcome = Groups.find({ _id: myGroupId }).outcome;
    return { inProgress: ( outcome === 'in progress'), won: ( outcome === 'won' ) };
  }
});
```

Here I'm returning an object from the helper instead of separate variables for *inProgress* and *won* to avoid searching Groups twice.

I've also modeled each user as belonging to one group with the *groupId* being a key in the user object. This obviously allows you to have any number of people in each group as well as any number of groups.

What I've left out is the server side logic that sets the *outcome* key in the Group documents. You'll have to set one group to *won* and the other to *lost* in the same server method.

Comment: Thx for solution, but problem is that I if some one `WIN` than I delete chat rooms and redirect users, so If some user will be online but not on chat room, ur `hmtl` shouldnt work

Comment: Your question isn't really answerable if you leave out important details. However, even if you redirect them to another URL you can still use the `{{#if won}}` part of the logic, just put that on the template for the *game over* url.

Comment: yep but I have such logic: If someone wins, than I destroy my collection with chat rooms `Rooms.remove()` so that path willnot exist `myapp/room/:id` and after redirect users, so If I will use  `{{#if won}}` and in `js` helper `if (Meteor.user().won) Router.go('result')` than I will have eternal redirect wherever the user has gone, because this `{{#if won}}` will be on my `layoutTemplate` which built the entire application

Answer (score 0):

You have a design problem.

1. and 2. If you want to track the "groups" (if they lose or win, redirect to win or lose) in your app, you have to create a group collection to manage the "states" of your game(I think your app is like a game).
2. with the group collection you can show the information to the members, i.e. if I'm in a group even if I was offline when I login in your app I will be able to see what is in my groups records.

Its a matter of design and know how manage the data and the events in meteor

Comment: room it's a "group" in every room I have array like `[id1,id2..]` , I know all anout this, I want to know how to track in all app when  some one win, and MULTI redirect users

Comment: Set sessions variables to track the current match

Comment: Session is not secure and every body can set session, soo

Comment: Meteor reactivity and magic is made around sessions variables... thats how you can track events, actions, etc in your app, if you will use meteor js you should be afraid to use sessions. you should check meteor-cookbook for more information.

Comment: ok. So I maybe solved my problem and here question for you, if I change some filed in `Meteor.user` and do on client such stuff `if (Meteor.user.win) ROuter.go('//)` it will be reactive ? Or everybody will need to reload page

Comment: My way to rediect user when they won: Set a session variable that check for scores when you press submit or send button (button event) and create some conditions when the score is checked. Knowing that when a group whin it will trigger your condition and you can return another session and trigger it in a template helper

Comment: yep, but when someone click on submit button, then ONLY for this user session sets, and ur solution doesn't solve how to redirect group of user or I misunderstood

Comment: check @michaelFloyd answer

Comment: Going through the [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) would really help you Qwe.